# C++ Subset array finder looping with comma at ending?

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
void choice();
void Start(){
 system("cls");
    char subset[100];
    int y,x;
    cout << "Enter a Set"<<endl;
    int pass = 0;
    while (pass < 1){
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
        cin >> subset;
            while(y < 100){
            if (subset[x+1] == '}') { cout<<"Invalid Set"<<endl<<"Enter a Set"<<endl; break; }
            if (subset[x] == '}'&& subset[0] == '{') {  cout << "Set Accepted"<<endl; pass = 1; break;}
            x = x+2;
            if (y == 99) {cout <<"Invalid Set"<<endl<<"Enter a Set"<<endl; } 
            y++;
            }
    }    
    int nofsubset = x / 2;
    int b = 1;
    char arr[99];
    int n = nofsubset;
        while(nofsubset!= 0) {
            for(int l=0; l<n; l++){
            //cin >> arr[l];
            arr[l] = subset[b];
            b = b + 2;
            }
            for (int i=0; i<(1<<n); i++){
            cout << "{";
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {    
                    if(i & (1 <<j)) {
                    cout << arr[j];
                    }       
                }
            cout <<"}"<<endl;
            }
            nofsubset = 0;
        }
    system("pause");
    choice();
}

void choice(){
    system("cls");
    cout <<"**************************"<<endl;
    cout <<"*                        *"<<endl;
    cout <<"*  1 - Generate Subsets  *"<<endl;
    cout <<"*  2 - Exit              *"<<endl;
    cout <<"*                        *"<<endl;
    cout <<"**************************"<<endl;
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 1){ Start();}
    else{ return ;}
}

int main() {
 choice();
}
```

this code would allow to find subset of set for example i entered {1,2,3} and it will generate

```
{}
{1}
{2}
{12}
{3}
{13}
{23}
{123}
```

what my professor want is to out put it on format with comma like this

```
{}
{1}
{2}
{1,2}
{3}
{1,3}
{2,3}
{1,2,3}
```

can anyone please help me edit my code i cant seem to just put "," on the loop array because itl produce {1,2,3,}

thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider printing the comma before any output after the first.

Comment: *can anyone please help me edit my code* -- The point of a homework exercise is for you to figure out how to structure your code so that it does what you want it to do.  This isn't just "editing of code".

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  If you must use character arrays, find a safer method because `cin >> subset` doesn't count the number of characters it input.  Try using `std::istream::read` or maybe a derivative of `std::getline`.

Comment: Note: `subset[x + 1]` will access undefined memory when `x == 99` because `subset[100]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
        cout << "{";
            bool first = true;
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {    
                if(i & (1 <<j)) {

                if (!first)  cout << ","; // <<< try this
                first = false;

                cout << arr[j];
                }       
            }
        cout <<"}"<<endl;
```